# Error establishing a database connection in localhost Wordpress site

Tags: localhost

I'm new to this - For some reason my localhost website stopped working and I've tried all of the popular recommended options and this didn't work. So I redownloaded MAMP and redownloaded Wordpress.

I am still getting this error. What could be causing this? The database, wp content, and wp-config.php aren't even up in the localhost folder, so it can't be that.

[image: This error]

Answer (score 0):

Have you:
- checked to ensure that the MySQL process is running locally?
- set up a user/pass for the database?
- used the same user/pass in the wp-config.php file?

That error usually means that the SQL server can't find or authenticate to the database.

Comment: The solution was the MYSQL user and password along with permissions!

Comment: If my answer was correct, then click the checkmark so others with a similar problem will be helped. Glad you got it working.